# How to split a text into strings?

Tags: scala, split

I want to split a text file into strings, can you please tell me how to split it. For example, the following text file is given:

```
this course in, a style  i 
will have to a modern, language that encourages 
writing clean; and elegant code in a good
```

Is there any possibility to split the text file into strings like following, for example by 2 words:

```
this course
in a
style i
will have
to a
modern language
that encourages
writing clean
and elegant
code in 
a good
```

Can you please give me some hints? Thank you in advance.

Comment: how about odd number of words in first line ??? how will you split them under 2 words splitting mechanism ???

Comment: Isn't it possible to go to next line and make it splitted. For example, 
    This car is red // 
    and expensive
Then if we split it by 3 words then, the output is like following
    This car is //
    red and expensive
Here I noted new line by "//".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to Luigi´s answer.

3) You should think about filtering out the punctuation.

4) Another hint:

```
scala> val list = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
list: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

scala> val listOfTwoElements = list.sliding(2).toList
listOfTwoElements: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2), List(2, 3), List(3, 4), List(4, 5), List(5, 6), List(6, 7), List(7, 8), List(8, 9), List(9, 10))
```

Comment: or, do a split on the string, convert to list and then zipWithIndex it. on each pair, you could mkString then ;-)

Comment: notice `sliding` gives you pairs starting on every element, rather than every other element

Answer (score 4):

Some ideas:

1) Use `java.util.Scanner` to read in tokens direct from the file using the `next(pattern: String)` method

or

2) Read in all lines (see `scala.io.Source`), concatenate them into a single string, `split` the string into an array, then use the `grouped` method to split that into sub-arrays of 2 elements